# Bootstrap Tooltip (3.3.6) shows grey box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap, initializing it at the start of my page:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then I have my class, where I want to have my hover on:

```
<div class="panel-body">
   <div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-orderstatus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!" style="width: 14.28%">
           Received
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And at the end I have:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  }); 
</script>
```

And finally, the result:

[image]

What exactly is going wrong?

I've checked the Tooltip version inside of Bootstrap.js, showing it's version: 3.3.6

Comment: Check your browser's inspector when you load the page. Do you get any JS errors - such as `tooltip()` or `$` *"is not a function/could not be found"* etc.?

Comment: Have you added jQuery before `bootstrap.min.js` as well ?

Comment: @GeoffJames I just checked, and no. not a single error.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman No, I haven't. Let me check, just a minute.

Comment: @Paramone - Like Muhammad has stated, you will need to include reference to the jQuery library *before* your `bootstrap.min.js`, as you're calling a jQuery function (`$` is jQuery) - otherwise it won't work; hence me asking about any errors in the Inspector's console - should be *"$ is not a function"* (or something similar)

Comment: @GeoffJames Yes, exactly! I didn't get an error however.. But once adding jquery, it all worked.
 - MuhammadUsman Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
  });
```

```css
.panel-body{margin-top:25px;}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel-body">
   <div class="progress">
       <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-orderstatus" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Hooray!" style="width: 14.28%">
           Received
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```